# Drag and drop CSS and font files from the Solution Explorer in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) Preview Version 17.1.0 Preview 1.0

Tags: html, css, text-editor, visual-studio-2022

I was used to drag-n-drop css and font files (.ttf & .otf) from the Solution Explorer onto a Text Editor as this saves much time. I noticed that I cannot do this in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.1.0 Preview 1.0.

I intend to drop the font files onto a CSS file then add a single CSS file onto an HTML page (RAZOR)

This works in VS IDE 2019 but not in 2022 Preview.

I have disabled and re-enabled the "drag and drop text editing" from Tools -> Options but with no success.

Is there a way to fix this or it does not work in my version of VS IDE 2022?

Comment: This feature does not yet exist in the new Razor editor in VS2022, or the LSP-based HTML and CSS editors (which are opt-in under Preview Features).  It is on our backlog.  Please send a feedback request so that we can prioritize it higher.

Comment: @Jimmy that's a pity, since it was available in previous VS... what should we use for a feedback request? Suggest a feature from Visual Studio? Or something else?

Comment: @Jimmy. Okay, will do so. The feature saves alot of time than manually writing everything. I appreciate your reply.

Comment: @Jimmy. I have just submitted a feedback request. I hope it will be added to the IDE.